# what does RUNNING_XACTS nextXid do pg_wal?

Tags: postgresql

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
select pg_current_wal_insert_lsn(); --yield C/2F3533D8
begin;
select pg_current_wal_insert_lsn(); --yield C/2F3533D8
update wal set id = id + 1;
select pg_current_wal_insert_lsn(); --yield C/2F3534D8
commit ;
select pg_current_wal_insert_lsn(); --yield  C/2F353500

select 'C/2F353500'::pg_lsn - 'C/2F3533D8'::pg_lsn; --yield 296
select file_name, upper(to_hex(file_offset)) file_offset from pg_walfile_name_offset('C/2F3533D8');
/*
        file_name         | file_offset
--------------------------+-------------
 000000010000000C0000002F | 3533D8
            */

select * from pg_ls_waldir() where name = '000000010000000C0000002F';
/* returning with the previous command.

             name           |   size   |       modification
--------------------------+----------+---------------------------
 000000010000000C0000002F | 16777216 | 2022-03-11 12:20:13+05:30
 */
```

---

then run in terminal.

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_waldump -p /var/lib/postgresql/14/main/pg_wal -s C/2F3533D8 -e  C/2F353500#
```

returns

```
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):     65/   197, tx:       1506, lsn: C/2F3533D8, prev C/2F3533A0, desc: HOT_UPDATE off 2 xmax 1506 flags 0x00 ; new off 3 xmax 0, blkref #0: rel 1663/24598/41820 blk 0 FPW
rmgr: Standby     len (rec/tot):     54/    54, tx:          0, lsn: C/2F3534A0, prev C/2F3533D8, desc: RUNNING_XACTS nextXid 1507 latestCompletedXid 1505 oldestRunningXid 1506; 1 xacts: 1506
rmgr: Transaction len (rec/tot):     34/    34, tx:       1506, lsn: C/2F3534D8, prev C/2F3534A0, desc: COMMIT 2022-03-11 12:20:03.642221 IST
```

--there is 3 records, differ with the book(https://prnt.sc/-OC1lF6kUxXM). Then I wonder what's the second record do?

```
rmgr: Standby  ... desc: RUNNING_XACTS nextXid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That WAL record has nothing to do with your transaction. It is written in the course of a checkpoint.

If `wal_level` is `replica` or higher, this record that contains details of the current snapshot (all active transactions and `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks) is written to WAL. This information is necessary so that queries on the standby know what they can see.